# Where do Green Lanterns' civilian clothes go when they are in uniform?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Superhero costumes have a *slight* tendency to be tight, revealing the shapes of almost every body part they cover. <sub>Except, thank God, for Hulk's pants.</sub>

This implies that superheroes have found a way to get rid of their civilian clothes before gearing up, otherwise some six- or eight-packs would be hidden by the super-suit molding a winter jacket, as well as other (mainly female) body parts writers judge worthy of attention. From where I stand, we can distinguish between several categories:

- **"I have super-speed, so one can assume I just drop my civilian clothes somewhere"**: Flash, Superman, Quicksilver...
- **"I don't have super-speed or any superpowers for that matter, but I manage"**: Daredevil, Green Arrow...
- **"I'm kind of a public figure so I can gear up without worrying too much about such things"**: Wonder Woman, Aquaman, Captain America, Iron Man, Fantastic Four...
- **"I don't care, I'm a shapeshifter"**: Martian Manhunter, Mystique...
- **"Shut up, it's magic"**: Zatanna, Doctor Strange...
- **"I'm Batman"**

And then there are Green Lanterns<sup>1</sup>. Green Lanterns have great flight speed, but no speed to gear up and ditch their blue jeans the way Superman could. In fact, in most cases the uniform just appears to somehow replace the clothes, as depicted in the cover below:

[image: Hal Jordan faces the viewer, pictured in the process of changing from civilian clothes (jeans, black t-shirt, brown flight jacket with wool collar and shoulder patch) into his Green Lantern uniform. A jagged glowing line runs from where his neck meets his left shoulder down and across his torso to the top of his right thigh. On his right hand his Lantern ring is glowing and the right part of his body is in Lantern uniform. Energy lines from his ring and his hair blowing to the left imply that the ring is transforming or replacing his clothes with his Lantern uniform.]

This is supported by the fact that when the suits rips, what is often shown is skin, like here:

[image: Jessica Cruz, in her Green Lantern uniform with a tear on the left thigh showing skin to which a bandage has been tied, is holding Simon Baz by the hand above a lava-filled, volcanic landscape. Flying insectoid creatures hover to the left. Simon's uniform is completely torn off of his left arm, down to his shoulder, leaving them bare.]

Though when it's needed for view angle reasons, Jessica gets her clothes back:

[image: Liseth Vok holds Jessica in the air by her throat. Jessica's uniform is patchy or torn, with a yellow glow around the edges. Her arms and legs, where the uniform is missing, are bare, but where her uniform is missing on her lower back and butt her t-shirt and jeans are visible.]

These examples are quite recent though, and Green Lanterns have been around for a while.

**Was it ever explained, in comics or elsewhere, where the civilian clothes go when their suit is on, or if they actually stay there, why the green uniform fits the abs despite leather jackets?**
<sub>(apart for the obvious out-of-universe reasons that breasts and abs sell more issues)</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually, I reckon every color of Lantern uniform behaves this way, but I'll just say with Green Lanterns for clarity. If the answer comes from another shade of the emotional spectrum, it's not a problem though!</sub>

Comment: Not an answer, but given that the Green Lantern corps is all about manipulating reality with their minds (and their rings), are you sure they're even wearing clothes in the first place?

Comment: @PeterM I thought this could be some kind of mind trick useful for the cops they are ("look at me abs, you stand no chance"), but then again, I'd think this would get mentioned _somewhere_ in like 60 years of existence.

Comment: Superman takes off Green Lantern's ring to reveal his day clothes underneath; http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/5/54562/3366129-how-superman-beat-green-lantern-2-2.jpg

Comment: In other continuities, the clothes teleport from one place to another by force of will; https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/0/40/1777272-greensuitsummon.jpg

Comment: @Valorum I wouldn't count _Injustice_ as cannon, especially about Lantern lore (they threw a lot away, ask the Red Lanterns), but I should have stated that. As for you other link, ok, then it's goofy magic from back in the days, it seems.

Comment: @Jenayah - Take your pick what's canon in a property that's run across nearly 80 years, twenty different comic serials, a dozen cartoons and films.

Comment: @Valorum in any case, the _Injustice_ situation - while proving that the clothes stay here - doesn't answer why the uniform is so fit. Given than I never saw a Lantern naked upon taking off his/her ring, I guess the clothes do teleport or _handwaving_ vanish

Comment: I want to say the ring transforms their clothes into their uniforms. I'd check the early Hal Jordan stories for an explanation of some sort - the writers back then almost always would provide some sort of science-y mumbo-jumbo to explain this sort of thing. Don't expect too much, though - Barry Allen kept his Flash costume compressed in a ring, and released it and then put it on. Which doesn't explain why it looks like it's skin tight, since the illustrations generally made it look like he put it on *over* his street clothes....

Comment: @RDFozz yeah, I knew that, which is _exactly_ while I tried to hide that nonsense behind "yup I just take 'em off real quick" :D as for the transforming their clothes, this is the most "reasonable" assumption so far (well, the ripped suit never turns back into ripped clothes, but hey), though I've never seen it stated.

Comment: Batman would also fall into Daredevil category.

Comment: @user931 Batman has his own category. "I'm Batman". :D FYI, I've also rollbacked because from what I know, Iron Man keeps his civilian clothes underneath the armor.

Comment: Actually, Stark *has* worn his armor under his clothes: throughout most of the 1960s, his armor prevented the shrapnel near his heart from killing him, so he basically wore it all the time. And, in the mid-1970s, he created an armor that he wore "de-polarized" as underwear; he could convert it to his armor, and the sleeves, legs, boots, gloves and helmet would slide into place. This is famous for three things: based on the time to deploy, it seemed likely that it would leave burns; his explanation required him to be talking at super-speed; and (on the plus side) it got rid of the armor's nose.

Comment: @RDFozz I didn't know! Funny and interesting, thanks for the info! :) then, unrollback is on the way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't trust cover art, it is notoriously misleading.

Apparently originally Hal Jordan physically took the suit off Abin Sur and put it on (it wasn't an energy construct) [comicvine forum](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/green-lantern/4015-41148/forums/off-my-mind-green-lanterns-suitfabric-or-energy-co-608701/).

[image: Image of Hal Jordan, in Green Lantern uniform, pulling on his glove. Narrative text reads "After Hal Jordan has followed the spaceman's orders in disposing of all remnants of him and his rocket..." Hal thinks to himself "The spaceman told me to take his special uniform! And I vowed to him that I would carry out my new responsibilities to the best of my ability!"]

If the Green Lantern movie is any indication, the suit goes over their clothes.

Also in the cartoons

According to the DC Database

> The Green Lantern's uniform is not made out of fabric. It is created by the Power Ring whenever the wearer wills to wear it. It automatically appears over the wearer's normal clothing, and vanishes when the wearer wills to return to their civilian attire.
> [Fandom page for Green Lantern Ring](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Ring)

That being said, the ring also has access to a pocket dimension (like where the lantern is sometimes hidden).

**So I believe either the clothes are tightly covered over the person's body, or they are moved into the pocket dimension while the suit is in place. And maybe it depends on the user / clothing. Because in your examples, some of them appear to be wearing minimal clothing under their suit, while Jessica clearly has normal clothes under the suit.**

Comment: Eh, in the end, covering clothes or not, it all boils down to comic book magic, does it :) I'm curious - is that first panel from the very first Green Lantern comics? (The Hal Jordan ones, not the Alan Scott ones).

Comment: @Jenayah I added a reference to where I got that image, so presumably it is the original Hal Jordan first comics.

Comment: Ah, indeed, traced it back. _Green Lantern_ #1, 1960, though [it's flipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEJsG.png) in the reprint, for whatever reason...

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the Green Lantern rings are able to store their super-suits and make them appear, it could be that the clothes just go into the rings while their superhero costumes are being worn. **However, the costumes could be constructs** (don't know too much lore so maybe that is illogical) and therefore not be stored and are just created instantly, in which case my logic about storing civilian clothes wouldn't be as sound.

EDIT: New theory: If the rings can transport their users like they did in one of the first chapters of Rebirth *Green Lanterns*, maybe they just **create the construct-clothes and teleport the normal clothes away for the time being**. BTW, I don't know a lot about Green Lantern lore, this is all just my thoughts. If nobody on this site has canon evidence of how this works, maybe someone on a Green Lantern forum or something has read every issue of the series ever and found something explaining this.

Comment: The wardrobe-ring could be (at least one Flash certainly uses those), but I don't remember even seeing one for the GLs. If you have a reference, I'd be curious! Should be noted however that the Green Lantern rings are more on the "pocket computer" side than the "miniature storage" one. As per the costumes being constructs, they probably are, but they would still be physically overlaying the leather jacket, so... Why do we see 'em abs? :p

Comment: I wouldn't take the cover as being canon if there is reasoning for something else being true that contradicts it.